# Threaded application does not stop with keyboard interrupt Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to stop the threaded python application with keyboard interrupt. One thread captures the images and put them in queue and the other thread saves the images to hardisk.

The code is here

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import os
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys


frames = Queue(50)
exitProgram = False
saveImages = True


class ImageGrabber(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ID=ID
        self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(ID)
        self.fps = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        self.w=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.h=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()
        cv2.imwrite("testImage.png",self.frame)
        print(f"Camera Opened with fps {self.fps}, width = {self.w}, and height = {self.h}")     
        
        self.stopped = False
        # self.adjustB = adjustBrightness(0.75)  

        
    
    def run(self):
        global frames
        global exitProgram
        while not self.stopped:
            if not self.grabbed or exitProgram is True:
                print("Exit Command reached")
                self.stop()
                self.cam.release()
            else:
                (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()               
                frames.put(self.frame)
                
                
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True


class imageSaveThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,grabber,filePath):
         
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global saveImages
        self.dateTime = self.getDateStamp()
        self.imgName = filePath + 'img_' + self.dateTime + '_'
        self.cntr = 0        
        
    def getDateStamp(self):    
        filedate = str(datetime.now())
        filedate = filedate[0:-7]
        filedate = filedate.replace(':', '_')
        filename = filedate 
        return filename

    def run(self):
        global frames
        while True:
            if(not frames.empty()):
                self.Currframe=frames.get()
                cv2.imwrite(self.imgName + str(self.cntr).zfill(6) + '.png',self.Currframe)
                self.cntr = self.cntr + 1
                print(f"Queue Size in writing = {frames.qsize()} and fram number = {self.cntr}")
            elif exitProgram is True:
                print("Exit Command imageSaveThread reached")
                print(f"Final Queue Size at exit = {frames.qsize()}")
                break         
      

def main():
    if saveImages == True:
        savefilePath = 'D:/111/'
        grabber = ImageGrabber(0)
        imageSaveThr = imageSaveThread(grabber,savefilePath)        
        grabber.start()
        imageSaveThr.start()
        e = threading.Event()
        # imageSaveThread.join()
        # grabber.join()
        print ('Press CTRL-C to interrupt')
        while grabber.isAlive():
            try: 
                time.sleep(5) #wait 1 second, then go back and ask if thread is still alive
            except KeyboardInterrupt: #if ctrl-C is pressed within that second,
                                      #catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception
                e.set() #set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
                exitProgram=True
                print ('Exiting...')
                grabber.join()
                imageSaveThr.join()
          
    else:
        videoCodec = 'h264'
        videoExt = 'mkv'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I I replace the main function and directly call the program then it works and exits the threads like the code below

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import os
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys


frames = Queue(50)
exitProgram = False
saveImages = True


class ImageGrabber(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ID=ID
        self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(ID)
        self.fps = self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        self.w=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        self.h=self.cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()
        cv2.imwrite("testImage.png",self.frame)
        print(f"Camera Opened with fps {self.fps}, width = {self.w}, and height = {self.h}")     
        
        self.stopped = False
        # self.adjustB = adjustBrightness(0.75)  

        
    
    def run(self):
        global frames
        global exitProgram
        while not self.stopped:
            if not self.grabbed or exitProgram is True:
                print("Exit Command reached")
                self.stop()
                self.cam.release()
            else:
                (self.grabbed, self.frame) =self.cam.read()               
                frames.put(self.frame)
                
                
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True


class imageSaveThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,grabber,filePath):
         
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global saveImages
        self.dateTime = self.getDateStamp()
        self.imgName = filePath + 'img_' + self.dateTime + '_'
        self.cntr = 0        
        
    def getDateStamp(self):    
        filedate = str(datetime.now())
        filedate = filedate[0:-7]
        filedate = filedate.replace(':', '_')
        filename = filedate 
        return filename

    def run(self):
        global frames
        while True:
            if(not frames.empty()):
                self.Currframe=frames.get()
                cv2.imwrite(self.imgName + str(self.cntr).zfill(6) + '.png',self.Currframe)
                self.cntr = self.cntr + 1
                print(f"Queue Size in writing = {frames.qsize()} and fram number = {self.cntr}")
            elif exitProgram is True:
                print("Exit Command imageSaveThread reached")
                print(f"Final Queue Size at exit = {frames.qsize()}")
                break         
      

savefilePath = 'D:/111/'
grabber = ImageGrabber(0)
imageSaveThr = imageSaveThread(grabber,savefilePath)        
grabber.start()
imageSaveThr.start()
e = threading.Event()
# imageSaveThread.join()
# grabber.join()
print ('Press CTRL-C to interrupt')
while grabber.isAlive():
    try: 
        time.sleep(5) #wait 1 second, then go back and ask if thread is still alive
    except KeyboardInterrupt: #if ctrl-C is pressed within that second,
                              #catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception
        e.set() #set the flag that will kill the thread when it has finished
        exitProgram=True
        print ('Exiting...')
        grabber.join()
        imageSaveThr.join()
```

I am not able to understand the reason. Can anyone tell me what is the reason?

Comment: If a variable is on the left side of an assignment anywhere in a function then that variable is local to this function (if not declared otherwise) and may shadow a global variable of the same name (which can't be modified then in this function).

Comment: If you are talking about `exitProgram` variable, now I changed it to global wherever it is being used but same problem. The problem is while pressing ctrl + c does not make it enter the `except` part of  `try catch` block

Comment: It was not entering the `while grabber.isAlive():` loop, I changed it `while grabber.is_alive()` and it worked in windows10

Answer (score 1):

PS(Would've added this as an comment, but I can't since I don't meet the requirements)

I'll leave the explanation to somebody else, since I was not able to get your code running on my computer.

But have you looked at adding an sys.exit(0) at the end of your except block? It made a difference for me whenever I tried to use KeyboarInterrupt to get out of this little code snippet:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
     while True:

         try:
             print("Hello")
         except KeyboardInterrupt:
             print("Exiting...")
             sys.exit(0)
```

PS: Use Ctrl+Z and kill the process manually if you end up removing the sys.exit() part.